# Zap global logger

Tags: go

Hello I want to use zap global logger

Right now I am using sugar_logger like this

```
        log_sugar.Infow("Start API",
            "protocol", "http",
            "host", config.Host,
        )
```

And response is `{"level":"info","ts":1638893668.7487385,"caller":"root/main.go:97","msg":"Start API.","host":"0.0.0.0:8080","protocol":"http","host":"0.0.0.0:8080"}`

but I want to use like this `zap.L().Info("replaced zap's global loggers")`

when I use like this

```
zap.L().Info("Start API",
            "protocol", "http",
            "host", config.Host,
        )
```

I get an error "too many arguments" how can I use global logger, what am I doing wrong

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Logger takes a format `string` and a list of `zap.Field`s.

```
zap.L().Info("Start API",
            zap.String("protocol","http"),
            zap.String("host",config.Host),
)
```

"too many arguments" because `zap.Info` takes a string and a variadic list of `Field`s, but you included too many strings and no `Field`s. The `string`s can't be `Field`s, so they ended up being extra string arguments and that doesn't fit the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zap.S()` instead, which returns a pointer to the global `SugaredLogger`.